# How to customize Serializer and Deserializer for Option in Gson without redundancy?

Tags: java, json, generics, gson

I'm now trying to customize the Serializer and Deserializer in Gson for `Option<T>` (using `io.vavr.control.Option`, or `Optional<T>` if using `java.utils.*`, which is similar here).

And there are 2 requirement for what I want:

1. I want to serialize `Option.none()` as `null` in JSON, and `Option.some("hello")` as `"hello"`, so that there is no redundancy (I'm assuming that the value inside `Option.some` is @NotNull).
2. I'm also hoping that an `Option<T>` value keep not changed after `serialize` and `deserialze`.

So, following is my try ([here](https://gist.github.com/luochen1990/bd63b2d6e9c7c9b77961208920ec3edf) is the full code, and I'm referencing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39193874/1608276) to solve the generic type issue):

```
public static class OptionJsonAdapter<T> implements JsonSerializer<Option<T>>, JsonDeserializer<Option<T>> {
    private final Type typeOfT;

    public OptionJsonAdapter(Type typeOfT) {
        this.typeOfT = typeOfT;
    }

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Option<T> src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        if (src.isEmpty()) {
            return JsonNull.INSTANCE;
        } else {
            return context.serialize(src.get(), typeOfT);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Option<T> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfRes, JsonDeserializationContext context) {
        if (json.isJsonNull()) {
            return Option.none();
        } else {
            return Option.some(context.deserialize(json, typeOfT));
        }
    }
}
```

But, above code cannot deserialize JSON `null` into `Option.none()`, even I indeed write a `if (json.isJsonNull())` branch,  it seems that the logical branch of the if-true case is never reached,  **when deserializing JsonNull,  Gson even havn't call our customized `deserialize()` function**.

So, how can I serialize and deserialize `Option` as what I want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to serialize Optional<T> classes with Gson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161366/how-to-serialize-optionalt-classes-with-gson)

Comment: @Marcono1234  Thanks!  this post solves part of my question -- about the generic type,  but dosn't answer my main question --  how to deserialize JsonNull with customized JsonDeserializer.

Comment: See the answer with the most votes there, it shows how to implement it for `Optional` (for `Option` it should be pretty similar). Trying to implement this with `JsonDeserializer` will not work, see [my comment](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1696#issuecomment-631358452) on your GitHub issue